# Does the tag "General" serve any purpose?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

[general](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general) has 20 questions associated with it.

I think it was originally intended to refer to general chemistry, but I don't think it's really important in that designation, either.  Pretty much any chemistry concept can, on some level, fit into the general chemistry curriculum, so at worst we'd be applying it to umpteen questions if we used it in that sense.

The actual population of questions tagged [general](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general) is a hodgepodge of things that may not have neatly fit into an existing tag at the time, but I think we have sufficient tag coverage at this point such that we can find a pigeonhole to put them in.

Does this tag have any purpose that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I haven't forgotten about http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/433/how-much-effort-is-enough-with-homework-problems-we-would-like-to-hear-all-id or the medicinal chemistry issues.  I will get to them! :)

Comment: Just kill it ;) I have just tagged one question that had no other tags with [tag:polymers], the others were closed anyway.

Comment: Kill it. With fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done this manually and grabbed some other necessary edits in the questions.  On the plus side, I have given fans of the front page lots of old "new" stuff to look at.

If it returns, I will request that it be purged permanently.

Answer (score 1):

It means general chemistry. In other words, the explanation is meant to be delivered in easy terms. Maybe not true reality, but something that is well understood and not mentally two tough to grasp. Also meant to denote questions which are categorized as general chemistry, such as trivial topics like molariy, combustion, electron configuration, ect.

It should not be used for an *ambiguous* category.

Comment: I have to disagree with you here.  We already got rid of it because everything on the site could be considered "general" chemistry one way or the other.  Please don't re-add it.